# What happens when a TARDIS falls over onto its door side?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

So you're in the TARDIS in a car park, and for some reason the TARDIS falls over and lands door side down. You are not a Time Lord, so you can't just press the "right yourself" button (if there even is one) but you are able to open the doors and stand on the concrete surface of the car park. Now, let's suppose you want to lift the TARDIS to its upright position. Are you lifting the weight of the police box, or the weight of all the rooms inside the TARDIS?
Edit: I'm not asking how much the TARDIS weighs, I'm asking whether it's the internal or external weight that would apply in these circumstances.

Comment: This is what you'd do if you were a Timelord;  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ui_pR76ehr8

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71101/what-is-the-tardis-true-weight?noredirect=1&lq=1 - This seems to address the edit. The interior weight includes a black hole so it's mostly likely the exterior weight that counts.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The actual question can be answered accurately without any reference to how much the Tardis weighs. The answer in fact is that there are scenes in _Logopolis_ (1981) which imply the Tardis has an emergency exit at the rear. The Doctor's escape onto the Barnet bypass 21 minutes into episode 1, after the two Tardises have become trapped inside one another in what Adric believes to be an infinite regression, appears to only be explainable by the existence of such an exit.

Comment: The presence of a black hole can't possibly cause the Tardis to weigh a few thousand tons. A black hole is the super-compressed remnant of a very massive star (only a star of more than 8 solar masses can undergo the type of collapse which forms a black hole). If you are weighing the Tardis by including the amount of mass in its black hole (i.e. if you wrongly ignore the fact that the black hole is on Gallifrey, not aboard the Tardis - see _The Deadly Assassin_, 1976), the additional mass would be on a stellar scale: the Tardis would weigh _billions_ of tons, not a mere few thousand.

Comment: Although the episode in question does not survive on film, so the point cannot be directly checked, it is suggested in some reports that in episode 1 of _The Wheel in Space_ (1968) the Doctor and Jamie leave the TARDIS through an emergency exit out of the back of the Police Box shell (http://guide.doctorwhonews.net/story.php?story=TheWheelInSpace quoting from  _Doctor Who: The Second Doctor Handbook_ by Howe, Stammers and Walker), which thus offers some support to the implication created by the events in episode 1 of _Logopolis_.