# What happens if the TARDIS lands on a really sloped hill where it's not flat?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

What happens if the TARDIS (or any of the other Time Lords' TARDISes) lands on a really sloped hill where it's not flat? Would it stay upright or would it fall over?

Comment: Depends on whether it's the Red Nose special or not.

Comment: Related [What happens when a TARDIS falls over onto its door side?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177248/21351)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRbbKbFvJuY

Comment: Not a hill/mountain, but we have the TARDIS on the side in 'Eleventh Hour'.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MKvk2jnL6s

Answer (score 6):

There's a slight discrepancy between the old series and the 2005 reboot in what would happen to the TARDIS's interior if the TARDIS's exterior is tilted.

As can be seen in the second episode of series 19's *Castrolova*, when the Fifth Doctor's TARDIS lands tilted the interior tilts with it.

However in *NuWho* *S7: E11*, the Eleventh Doctor says

> The TARDIS is special. She has her own gravity, I'd explain if I had some charts and a board pen.

when the salvage team step inside of the TARDIS while on its side but find themselves right way up once through the doors. Furthermore, Twelve's TARDIS is horizontal while in Clara's bag during *S8: E9* but the Doctor continues to walk around upright while stuck in the TARDIS. He can even "Addams Family" the miniature exterior from horizontal to vertical to escape an oncoming train. However, when the miniature TARDIS falls back onto its side a moment later in the scene the interior does quake although its orientation doesn't change.

Regarding what happens only to the exterior, the TARDIS can fall over if tilted too far, although this may be able to be countered if the Doctor knows the TARDIS won't be materialising upright. In the video @Valorum commented with, the TARDIS can fall if the ground beneath it gives way and it becomes unbalanced. However, in *S6: E2* of *NuWho* the Doctor successfully materialises the TARDIS flush with the vertical face of a building, indicating that it doesn't have to fall from a tilted surface if it is known to be materialising onto one.

Comment: I have a faint memory of the control room flooding once due to the TARDIS overturning. I think it was because of the 'lower level water tanks' (maybe also swimming pool?)

Comment: @Danny3414 The Swimming Pool ended up in the Library (or vice versa) in _The Eleventh Hour_, series 5 episode 1 ("We meet Amelia Pond").  We see the Doctor wet as he climbs out the door, but the control room is not shown.  He does fall "into" the Tardis when climbing back in. However, there's room for debate as to whether this is due to the Tardis' orientation (lying sideways on the ground) or the Tardis' state (Regenerationatively).

Comment: Don't forget Matt Smith's entrance into the series. The TARDIS was on its side and he had to climb a rope to get out. I believe because the internal gravity was damaged.

Answer (score 3):

## The TARDIS would likely fall over, as it has before

While not exactly the situation you described, the Third Doctor serial "[The Curse of Peladon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_of_Peladon)" has the TARDIS land on a mountain slope where it begins rocking, going to about a 30 degree angle. Shortly afterwards, some high winds pick up and it falls over, off the mountain (but being indestructible, it remains intact).

Note that in this case, the TARDIS materialized without issue and the Doctor noted that it was a "smooth landing". It's unclear what would happen if it tried to materialize at, say a 60 degree angle, but I suspect the Doctor wouldn't report a "smooth landing".